# Javascript: Replace repeated character in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I've been solving katas on codewars and I stumbled upon a general code problem that I can't seem to find an answer to.

This is my code:

```
function wave(str) {
   let arr = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
       str[i].match(/\S/) && arr.push(str.replace(str[i], str[i].toUpperCase()));
   }
   return arr;
 };
```

(Note: Input is always lowercase.)
In the case of `wave("abc def");` the code does exactly what I want it to:

```
["Abc def", "aBc def", "abC def", "abc Def", "abc dEf", "abc deF"]
```

=> Function takes a string, capitalizes one letter of the string starting at `str[0]`, pushes the new word to `arr`, increments `i` and repeats process until `i < str.length`, then returns `arr` with all the results.

However, if I input `wave("acc def");` for example, only the first occurrence of the letter `c` will return capitalized:

```
["Acc def", "aCc def", "aCc def", "acc Def", "acc dEf", "acc deF"]
```

Question: Why does it 'jump' the second occurrence of 'c' and how can I target the second or nth occurrence of a character in a string?

Comment: _"only the first occurrence"_ ~ Try global matching `/\S/g` ?

Comment: `str.replace(str[i], ...)` will only replace the _first occurrence_ of the character at `str[i]` (hence it would also not work with `cac def`)

Comment: take the part left of `str[i]` (`.slice()`), take the uppercase version of `str[i]`, take the part right of `str[i]` (`.slice()`) - combine them again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are saying `str.replace(str[i], str[i].toUpperCase())`, you are saying: "Replace the first occurrence of `str[i]` with `str[i].toUpperCase()`" and this is exactly what your program is doing.

Consider building your new string like this:

```js
str.substring(0, i) + str[i].toUpperCase() + str.substring(i+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace("x", "y")` replaces the first occurrence of `"x"` in `str` with `"y"`
If there are only unique characters in the string your approach works, but it will fail when there are duplicated characters like in `"acc def"`

You could [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the string into three parts:

- The part left of `i` -> `.slice(0, i)`
- The character at index `i` -> `str[i]`
- The remaining part after index `i` -> `.slice(i + 1)`

Modify `str[i]` as required and combine them back into a single string with `.join("")`

```js
function wave(str) {
  const result = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (!str[i].match(/\S/)) continue;
    
    result.push([
                  str.slice(0, i),      /* the part left of str[i] */
                  str[i].toUpperCase(), /* str[i] */
                  str.slice(i + 1)      /* the remaining part right of str[i] */
                ].join(""))  // combine the parts in the array into a string
  }
  
  return result;
 };
 
 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(wave("abc def")));
 console.log(JSON.stringify(wave("acc def")));
```